# Creating .net application with specific arcgis functionalities

Tags: c#, .net, interpolation, arcgis, arcobjects

I am new to arcgis. I have given the task to create .net desktop application that can perform specific arcgis functions like digitization, interpolation etc. So my questions are

Can i develop application in .net to perform specific functionalities of arcGis like interpolation etc.

If yes how much time will be required for intermediate level developer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i develop application in .net to perform specific functionalities of arcGis like interpolation etc.

Yes, you can. ARCGIS does provide tools that be used in winform application. But, first of all make sure that your organization will purchase license for ARCGIS. It is not free and quite expensive.

> how much time will be required for intermediate level developer

This involves GIS skills along with application development skills. And as none of us know your skill set, therefore we cannot tell that.

Comment: Is there any video tutorial which may be helpful to achieve this goal..

Comment: @ZainAliMughal you can find all the stuff you need from the downloads that are available on their website and documentation. i used that a few years back and they had quite a lot of stuff available in their download package and their website.